Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) - Pass Server Response Locals to View
I am setting up an LWR server and attempting to get the CSRF Token that is generated by the Express app to be made available via the View so I can place it into a form that is posting back.
LWR App.mjs
// Create the LWR App Server
const lwrServer = createServer();
let app = lwrServer.getInternalServer('express');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    store: new SQLiteStore({ db: 'sessions.db', dir: './var/db' })
}));
app.use(csrf());
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var msgs = req.session.messages || [];
    res.locals.messages = msgs;
    res.locals.hasMessages = !! msgs.length;
    req.session.messages = [];
    next();
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('CSRF Token: ' + req.csrfToken());
    let csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    res.locals.csrfToken = csrfToken;
    next();
});

lwr.config.json
(note that I am testing out a RouteHandler to see if that will give me any access but no success yet)
{
    "routes": [
        {            
            "id": "Login",
            "path": "/login",
            "contentTemplate": "$contentDir/login.njk",
            "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/main_layout.njk",
            "bootstrap": {
                "ssr": true
            },
            "routeHandler": "$rootDir/src/routeHandlers/addCsrfToken.ts"
        }
    ]
}

I have attached my debugger and can see the res.locals are being properly set, though they aren't delivered into the view. I have debugged through view-middleware.js (under @lwjrs/core) and see that the 'req.params' are supposed to pass into the viewRequest, but even when I tested that (which is not ideal even if it worked), the 'req.params' are empty by the time it get's to this portion of the LWR handling.
Summary
I am looking for a way to pass values from the server over to the view. I know I can override the routeHandler, and in there I can assign variables that are passed into the view. However, from this override I don't see a way to access the underlying app/server.
My ultimate goal is to be able to get Passport.js integrated using the LWR server route/view process and then to be able to know when a user is logged in via the view and I am concerned none of this information will pass from the app server. I am sure the there is a way / best practice to pass information to the view from the server - look forward to thoughts (even if the answer is that I should leave the native views "simple" and use LWC component callbacks to the server to get all the info I need).

My ultimate goal is to be able to get Passport.js integrated using the LWR server route/view - why, what are you trying to accomplish? See XY Problem

I want to have authorized users on my web app, and Passport.js was just the method of choice at this point. This is a node.js hosted implementation of LWR so I don't have the benefit of Salesforce native authentication. From the documentation, it appears LWR itself (or LWC OSS) doesn't have an authentication framework integrated. Still learning though, so any advice is appreciated.

LWR on Node is a bleeding edge feature, it's still a developer preview. Our advice: if you're building a webapp without any Salesforce stuff , LWR should be dead last on the list of possible frameworks.

Yes, I understand it is still developer preview. I use LWC in Salesforce and wanted to start cross-expanding the use case via LWC OSS, and I believe they recommend LWR going forward. So, I was trying to test out the use cases for LWR on Node.js. I agree, I might not be able to utilize it yet in production, and to that extent, might not be even able to get a best practice answer as it is still too new. I will leave this question up in hopes there is a recommended way, and also explore other server options that still allow LWC component usage. Thanks for feedback.
